# Passing a local buffer to function

Tags: c, buffer

I am passing a local buffer to a function:

```
void func1()
{
    char buffer[128];
    func2(buffer); 
}

void func2(char *buff)
{
     strcpy(buff, "Some String");
}
```

Now when I look at the value of buff after function call, it just has "S" and rest is empty.

Now, if I make buffer global or static, then I can rx the whole string.

My question here is that we are passing the address of buffer to the function, so it should not matter if it is local or global. But, for the case of declaring as local, I do not get data back in my buffer.

Comment: It prints `Some String` to me. It is, however, not a good practice to do this kind of buffer manipulation...

Comment: @Diego, why not?  It's a very common idiom in C.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is not a good practice?

Comment: @jscode, it's just fine.  `accept(2)` works exactly this way, for example.

Comment: @Carl, @jscode, I don't like exposing stack-based local buffers to outer functions. I like them more to be dynamically-allocated. Call me too stack-based exploit safe :)

Comment: @Diego:  That is not what is happening, the buffer *belongs* to the "outer" function.

Comment: Useful information would be: What RTOS?, What target? How many tasks? How much stack space allocated to this task?

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared your buffer on the stack, it is *undefined* after `func1` exits. If you declared it to be global or static, however, its scope would not be restricted to the function call and thus you could continue to access it. Just having the buffer's address does not magically make its contents valid.

Comment: I check the value just in the function

Comment: Not according to your question: "Now when I look at the value of buff *after function call*, it just has 'S' and rest is empty."

Comment: Chris, after the function call refers to the `func2` function call, not `func1`, because after the `func1` call the variable just doesn't exist.

Comment: As @Chris has said, your buffer was placed on the stack. The reason you may still be able read the buffer (even though it's out of scope) is because the memory that it points to still happens to contain valid data, however it is surely doomed to be overwritten when the stack climbs back up -- for instance by calling another function.

Comment: @Peter: How would he be able to read the buffer? Under what name if the buffer itself is out of scope (and out of name)?

Comment: @Diego, thats true. I suppose not in the code above, but if he were to have returned the buffer at the end of the function, then that pointer would point to invalid data.

Comment: @Diego True, the buffer should be valid after `func2` but before `func1` exists. If that's the case, though, @jscode needs to say so explicitly and clarify precisely what "looking at the value of buff" entails.

Comment: I figured out what is happening....but could not find what makes it happen... I had another function func3() which was also calling func2() (func2 is fairly long buffer manipulation function)..So, func3() was calling func2(buff) where buff was a global buffer. So, in case I call func2() from func1() and if the buffer is local then I do not get the required string back in buffer rather I do not get back there, I go back to func3()/.....I do not know what is going on......but for sure I think in between the return from function call program goes somewhere else....this is s RTOS

Answer (score 2):

When you say "the value of *buff" in the debugger, you realize that is just one character of the string, right? The rest of the characters are next to it on the stack.

I'm not going to bother running this code. Everyone else here says it is working just fine.

Comment: I originally thought that this might have been the actual solution—verifying the content of the entire buffer with `printf` rather than with the debugger—but @jscode's response to my answer makes it clear that it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok - how are you looking at the contents of the buffer?  If you add a `printf("%s\n", buffer)` at the end of `func1()`, you'll see that it's working just fine.

Comment: I have a break point just after the function call. And I can see just the first char from func2.

Comment: @jscode, as other people have mentioned, there's no reason that buffer has to contain useful data after the function call.  Since you don't *do* anything with `buffer` after that point, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants to with that memory.  Add the `printf()` call - you'll see it works as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious what is wrong here, but since you have tagged the question "RTOS", is it possible that this task's stack is too small to accommodate a 128 byte array?